# Can't Find "Syslog.conf" in linux kernal 2.6.37.6 created with BuysBox v1.19.3

Tags: c, linux, syslog

I created a tiny OS for my controller with Linux kernel 2.6.37.6 with the help of BusyBox and tool chain. I am writing a logging module(C program) in it and i want customized logs(customized path for different logs) like in `/log/`. 
I have `syslogd` in my machine and `/etc/syslog.conf` supposed to present in my machine but it's not it the place. I created new `syslog.conf` under `/etc` but still i can't find my logs in desired place.

But if i run command `syslogd -O /log/Controller.log` all logs started to redirect to this (specified file). So i want to know where is the `configuration file` for this `syslogd` i can't find the configuration file for it.

Is there any way that i can write a module(program) for LOGS without requiring `syslog.conf` and yes of course traditional `printf` way. Problem is that for customized paths for `log` we need to give keyname `LOG_LOCAL1` in `openlog()` as a argument but it's not working

I followed procedure from this examples http://www.codealias.info/technotes/syslog_simple_example

Comment: Do you have a /etc/rsyslog.conf ?

Comment: no i don't have this(/etc/rsyslog.conf) too as well as /etc/syslog-ng.conf.

Comment: are you using busybox's syslogd?

Comment: Yes!! is it different from normal syslogd?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Busybox's syslogd then there is no support of syslog.conf,all logs are written to /var/log/messages by default.

You can modify code of syslogd in busybox which is located in **busybox/sysklogd/syslogd.c** for your desire behaviour

You can change code of syslogd like this

```
static const struct init_globals init_data = {
    .logFile = {
        .path = "your desire path",
        .fd = -1,
    },
```

Comment: Is there any way to add different log files for different requirement? after looking the code it seems difficult? what you say ?

Comment: Yes its difficut but you can change code accordingly